# Xcrun : error: unable to find utility "Validation", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, app-store, osx-yosemite

I am trying to automate app store submissions. As of know I was able to archive and export .ipa but got stuck on the following step

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation Project.ipa
```

Error: **Xcrun : error: unable to find utility "Validation", not a developer tool or in PATH**

I am running OS X 10.10.5 and Xcode 7.2.1

Comment: have you got any solution